# How to view a Collada mesh in a Qt application?

Tags: qt, 3d, collada

How do I create a small 3D viewport and show there a Collada mesh? Also, mesh has textures, and user would want to rotate and zoom in/out with a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) supports the Collada file format, and provides a choice of [Qt widgets](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Community/WindowingToolkits).

You may need to install the [OSG Collada Plugin](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Support/KnowledgeBase/Collada).

I used OpenSceneGraph with Qt nearly 3 years ago, and it was a very good experience. I found the mouse control to be very pleasing.

They released version 3.0.0 in June this year, and 3.0.1 in July, suggesting that it is still being actively worked on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Looking into it will take time, as it seems, Qt/MinGW support isn't provided in the binaries, so I'll have to try compiling it myself. I'll try to post here, if I make any progress )